# Check does shared hosting allow nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I started learning nodeJs I done few things on localhost. I was looking up how to set it up on shared hosting server. I found that many host servers are made for only php and they do not allow node? Or I did not understand it well? Now my question is how can I check does my hosting services allows installing nodeJs?

Comment: You understood correctly. You simply need to search for nodejs hosting. Have a look here https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Node-Hosting not sure how up to date it is tho

Comment: *"how can I check does my hosting services allows installing nodeJs?"* Have a look at the description of your host service?

Comment: It does not say a lot basics only.. I contacted them but nothing yet...

Answer (score 1):

Honestly man, if you are trying to do any development that falls out of the scope of a very basic web application, I would move away from shared hosting. Now, I am making an assumption that when you say "shared hosting", you mean something like godaddy's basic web hosting packages etc, which would more than likely not allow Node since you would need to be able to log into server and install and configure node, etc, which they do not allow since they keep you very "encapsulated" using a simple GUI / Cpanel type of environment.

So the best idea would be to honestly simply ask your shared hosting provider if they allow you ssh into the server and install / configure software, or instead why not spin up a small little server and use node on there using one of the major server providers such as [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/), [Linode](https://www.linode.com/) or [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/). While this is still technically shared hosting, with those providers, you are essential given "full control" of your instance so you can install and configure whatever software you like.

There are tons of tutorials which can walk you through setting up a small linux instance and installing node on these providers:

https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/

https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nodejs/a-nodejs-installation-crash-course

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tags/node-js?type=tutorials

Best of luck!

Comment: I knoow that with digital ocean and I saw how to install it and everything I just tought can it be done with some of shared hosts.

Comment: Understood. Well hopefully they get back to you soon?

Comment: Nothing yet I am waiting. And some personal question I will make another post for it how is it better to pay own server because of node or something because I want to make some social website for my friends and me. We don't like facebook. Too many fake people. So is it better whole server or some host? It would be around 10 000 people from start. And how much can database have content.. And for MariaDB it is same as node it needs to be installed ... SO I am wondering about that too...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this. I have successfully been able to set it up a couple different ways. I think the **second is probably what you want** :

**1. cgi-node** http://www.cgi-node.org/home

Basically this replaces PHP on the lamp stack. You can run javascript through node like you would run PHP. This has all the same functionality of node js but is only really geared towards template rendering.

```
    <html>
    <body>
     <?
       var helloWorld = 'Hello World!'; 
       write(helloWorld + '<br/>'); 
     ?>
     <?= helloWorld ?>
    <br/>
    <b>I can count to 10: </b>

    <?
      for (var index= 0; index <= 10; index++) write(index + ' ');  
    ?>
      <br/>
      <b>Or even this: </b>
    <?  
      for (var index= 0; index <= 10; index++) { 
    ?>
        <?= index ?> 
    <? } ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

**OR**

**2. Standalone Server** (this works with NameCheap hosting and GoDaddy shared hosting)

In your shared hosting account you will need SSH in order to do this. So you may need to upgrade or request SSH access from their customer support. Download the latest NodeJS https://nodejs.org/en/download/. The shared hosting is probably in linux 64 bit. You can check this on linux or unix by running :

```
uname -a
```

Download the Linux binaries and put the bin/node (and the bin/npm file if you want to use npm on the server) file from the download in /home/username/bin/ (create the bin folder if it doesn't exist) on the server. Put permissions 755 on the node binary. So you should have a new file here :

`/home/username/bin/node`

Open up the .htaccess file in /home/username/public_html and add the following lines :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  (.*)  http://localhost:3000/$1  [P,L]
```

Create a file in /home/username/public_html and just call it app.js. Add the following lines in that file :

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('NodeJS server running on Shared Hosting\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

SSH into the server run these commands :

```
cd /home/username/public_html
which node # this should return ~/bin/node
node app.js & # This will create a background process with the server running
```

If you can get this set up right this will save you a ton of money in the long run as opposed to using something like AWS or Heroku etc.