# NodeJs deployment on a site with content already on it

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, web-deployment

I'm trying to start developing apps with nodejs, I already have a site and a host. The thing that I am hitting a snag on is that I already have content on the site. I'm trying to start with making a basic oAuth app. Instead of having it on the home directory I want it run in one folder/subdomain. Currently I have http://spasiannrd.me. I want the app to run on https://spasiannrd.me/auth or https://auth.spasiannrd.me. Obviously if I can get it to run on /auth then the subdomain is easy. I've been doing research on how to deploy a basic nodejs package to a site. I'm basing code from nodes site, via https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/. Along with with editing the .htaccess with code similar to what is shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213799/3450678

I have the oAuth App ready to go but I just need to deploy it.

I just want to make sure I can deploy it so I'm starting off with a basic nodejs app, So far this what I have:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^auth(.*)$ https://localhost:3000/auth/$1 [P]
```

Currently I already have it configured to redirect /cpanel to the control panel and change http to https. I'm not entirely sure how RewriteRule works. It doesn't make much sense on how it works with another sub directory whilst listening to a port. <strike>I was thinking `^auth$` instead of `(auth/.*)` but doesn't seem to help.</strike>

app.js

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = 'spasiannrd.me';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('NodeJS server running on Shared Hosting\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at https://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Once I get this to work I should be able to figure out how to do the  rest. I already have node installed on the host and it runs other apps fine, just not able to have the application interact with the front end of things.

Comment: change this line RewriteRule (auth/.*) https://localhost:3000/auth/ [P,L]
to RewriteRule ^auth(.*)$ https://localhost:3000/auth/$1  [P] and make sure that you enable  mod_proxy

Comment: @MohammedElhag without the http:// prefix, it shoots out a 500, with the prefix it shoots out a 503

Comment: i have already wrote it with http + s but they ommited in comment so what i want to say is to change (auth/.*) to ^auth/(.*)$  then captured (.*) in target by $1